# How do I replace one PowerApp app with another in the same PowerApp environment?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a canvas app `My App - Test` that I'd like to save to `My App` in the same PowerApps environment (Office 365).

I tried using `Save As`, but it just created a new instance of `My App`.

The reason I'd like to save `My App - Test` to `My App` is because my users have a link to `My App`, and I don't want to break that link.

I understand that the Power Platform has an [Application Lifecycle Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/alm/basics-alm) process that I did not follow.  I'm happy to rectify that, but I only have one environment, so I don't know how I'd do the needed setup and migration.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save to computer + import

Back in the day, we used to export canvas apps into .msapp files and import them back, overwriting apps. This helped us fix many broken connection references, etc. The last time I tried it resulted in a new instance though. Worth a try, PowerApps Studio also evolves, functionality changes.

2. Via solutions

Add 'My App' to a solution A, and 'My App - Test' to solution B.
Export and download both.
Now you have to 'fool' PowerApps into believing that the exported solution B .zip file is in fact an update to solution A. For that you'll need to update the exported .zip file's contents:

- solution name must match solution A.
- solution version number must be higher than solution A's version.
- the canvas app's name (and probably ID) must be copied from solution A.

Not an ideal situation. Textbook ALM is of course always preferable.

Comment: For #1 in your answer, the export generates a .zip file and I don't see how to change the name of the app in the zip file to the desired target.

Comment: Open the app for editing, and use 'Download a copy' from the Save dropdown.